# How to deploy Django project using FTP or cPanel on Hostgator

Tags: python, django, deployment, ftp, cpanel

I've built a Django project with Python and a MySQL database. I'm ready to deploy it to a shared server hosting platform called Hostgator. Their tech support tells me to load all my project files directly into a public_html directory, but when I do that, and navigate to my domain, I just see a list of files (see below), instead of the website I built. What am I missing?
[image: screenshot of my site as is]

I can't find any good documentation for this kind of deployment. I've done the Django deploy checklist and I think I have that stuff done right. I'm wondering about if/what to put in an .htaccess file, and I'm also not sure how to configure my STATIC_URL or STATIC_ROOT. Do I need to update those to have the path of my production domain? I have run the collectstatic command on the project.

As of now, I have the following for my static file handling in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your django app in public_html. If you are using nginx or apache (you are using one of them, probably visible in the lower left of your screenshot just out of crop range), you likely want to proxy to the process running your Django app (gunicorn is one way to do that).

Essentially, Nginx handles all the web traffic, and hands off (via proxy) anything for your Django app to Gunicorn which is running your wsgi application (Django). Nginx can also then serve up your static files as well.

Digital ocean has a decent 'how to' that covers most of it in depth.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yeah, it's an Apache server. Will the link you sent work for Apache?

Comment: Also, I have an MySQL database setup. Will there be much difference between that and postgres?

Comment: configuration in Apache will be similar: https://medium.com/@thishantha17/build-a-simple-python-rest-api-with-apache2-gunicorn-and-flask-on-ubuntu-18-04-c9d47639139b#191a

Comment: process for mysql will be similar (create database, create user) but directions are slightly different. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database

Comment: No. Sorry, ask your questions here on s/o.

Comment: Thanks mate! I actually got it sorted